# Flexbox set height to 0

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm currently working on a react native application and I have an issue with flex.
At each time I add `flex: 1` in the style of a `View` or a `Text` element, its height equal 0, which cause the element to disapear.

This is what I'm trying to design:
[image: design]

(of course the colors are only here to help the comprehension)

My code:

```
return (
    <View style={{paddingVertical: 7, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: "center", justifyContent: 'center', height: 50, borderWidth: 1}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                     <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>                     <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#0f0'}}>
                         <Text>
                             First name Last name
                         </Text>
                     </View>
                     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                         <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                             27 km
                         </Text>
                     </View>
                 </View>
             </View>
             <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                 <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Booked ride</Text>
             </View>
         </View>
     </View>
     <View style={{flex: 0}}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onTake}>
             <Text style={styles.btnBox}>
                 Take
             </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
 </View>
)
```

This is what I currenlty have (with two elements repeated):
[image: current]

Comment: why is there a `flex: 1` on the booked ride View?

Comment: Because I need that my "Firstname lastname 27km" View has the same height than "Booked ride" View, it's the orange block on my scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first nested `<View>` is useless, remove it and adjust the next one like this:

```
return (
  <View
    style={{
      paddingVertical: 7,
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: 50,
      borderWidth: 1,
    }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#0f0' }}>
            <Text>First name Last name</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>27 km</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Booked ride</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 0 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onTake}>
        <Text>Take</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
```

I've also created a snack in case you want to take a look: [example](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/frowning-pastry).
Now you can align your texts as you pref :)